# building matplotlib from source on fedora 19, and found no freetype header files

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, freetype

i had installed matplotlib source package on a fedora 19 system, and got the following information:

```
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
    matplotlib: yes [1.3.1]
        python: yes [2.7.6 (default, Jan  9 2014, 14:24:42)  [GCC
                4.8.1 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1)]]`
      platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
         numpy: yes [version 1.8.0]
      dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                     axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                     install it after matplotlib.]
       tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                install it after matplotlib.]
     pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                install it after matplotlib.]
         pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
        libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                be found. Using local copy.]
      freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ftbuild.h)
                could not be found. You may need to install the
                development package.]
           png: yes [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                be found. Using unknown version.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
   sample_data: yes [installing]
      toolkits: yes [installing]
         tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
        macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
        qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
       gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
     gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairo to be installed.]
        gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk.]
         tkagg: no  [TKAgg requires Tkinter.]
         wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
           gtk: no  [The C/C++ header for gtk (gtk/gtk.h) could not
                be found.  You may need to install the development
                package.]
           agg: yes [installing]
         cairo: no  [cairo not found]
     windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
        dvipng: yes [version 1.14]
   ghostscript: yes [version 9.07]
         latex: no
       pdftops: yes [version 0.22.1]

============================================================================
                * The following required packages can not be built:
                * freetype
```

however, before this installation, i had already installed freetype 2.5.2 in default directory, that is, `/usr/local`. I found the header file(`ft2build.h`) in `/usr/local/include/freetype2`. The `setupext.py` is also checked, in the code part of `class FreeType(SetupPackage)`, there are

```
the default_include_dirs=
          ['freetype2','lib/freetype2/include','lib/freetype2/include/freetype2',]
```

now, i don't know why the package could not find the installed freetype. do somebody have some ideas? Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: did you install it via yum or by hand?

Comment: and on my system, the headers are installed in `/usr/lib`.  I suspect that you did the freetype installation by hand.  You either need to use the packaged dev version, or the path you actually installed freetype to to the list of directories (strongly suspect they are all relative to `/usr`)

Comment: Also note that the fedora `freetype-devel` package installs the headers into `/usr/include` (https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/freetype-devel/) on `/usr/local/include`.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it simply replacing 'ft2build.h' by the entire pathway of my ft2build.h (as suggered by tcaswell) in setupext.py, in self._check_for_pkg_config().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your helps!

yes, i install all these packages manually, since my pc with linux system donot connect to internet.

before i find your replying, i have solved the problem in an indirect way ;-( ,and here are what i have done:

since the devel package for freetype 2.5.2 is no convenient for my fedora 19 system, so i had to choose using freetype 2.4.11-6 with its devel package, and the dependency is ok now. i personally suspect it's a problem of environmental path-setting, but i have no time to test it at that time. in fact, the source package of freetype 2.5.2 already includes the devel sub-directory.

BTW, the manual installation of matplotlib are complicated, excluded the must packages: libpng and numpy, your still need to install distribute、backports.ssl_match_hostname、tornado、six、dateutil and pyparsing. only after all these installations are over, the matplotlib can finally be installed in your system.

Comment: Yes, matplotlib has a lot of external dependencies.  There should probably be an easy way to turn off the webagg stuff so tornado is not required, but `six`, `dateutil`, and `pyparsing` are definitely essential packages. http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html probably needs updating.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on cygwin 64 on Windows 7, using pip install: solved after installing pkg-config.